# Any Sublime Text plugin to wrap generated js automatically with anonymous function

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, sublimetext2, sublime-text-plugin

Is there any coffee script plugin or some kind of option which would wrap the generated javascript automatically with anonymous function on compile?

I know Web Essentials 2013 for Visual studio has this kind of option.

This coffee...

```
 foo () ->
    return 'bar'
```

...would compile to this:

```
(function() {
   var foo;

   foo = function() {
     return 'bar';
   };

}).call(this);
```

Instead of this:

```
 var foo;

 foo = function() {
   return 'bar';
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what coffeescript package you are using. In "Better Coffeescript"-package you just have to set "noWrapper": false in your package settings.